# Accessing an ASP.NET Application from Desktop Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, desktop-application

I have a ASP.NET MVC 6 applications running in Azure, currently accessible from a browser.
I want to access that same application using a Windows desktop application.
How do I expose the asp.net application logic to the desktop application?

Answer (score 1):

Your MVC Application is a web server feeding pages on URL requests and it returns the information directly to the web page calling it. You could try to create a web view within your desktop application but you will never be really involved with the data returned within your desktop App.

You would best looking to recreate the functions within an API in your MVC Site which would then just return the data you required and you can then create a view within your desktop application to show the data.

There are many examples of setting up API's in MVC, Google is your friend to lead you from here.